# How can I create a new column in a dataframe that is computed with the difference of two rows of the df from the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

I wan to create a function  to create a novel feature in my dataframe that takes into account the number of weeks that have passed since the Deal (which is a boolean column 1,0) is finished. If there was never a deal I want to have value =0 if the deal is still on I want the value to be 0. If there is no deal and there was one in the past I want to have the count of the weeks that are passed from the moment it was off. I don't have always all the observations for every week so I use the difference between the weeks.
The rows in the dataframe are ordered by cdsiAsin and dp_AcquisitionWeek.

The function that I created is the following one:

```
def NofWeeksfromDealfinish (df):
    df["NofWeeksfromDealfinish"] = 0 
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i==0:
            df.at[i, "NofWeeksfromDealfinish"] = 0
        
        elif df.loc[i]["Deal"] == 1:
            df.at[i, "NofWeeksfromDealfinish"] = 0
         
        else: 
            
            j = i - 1 
            if df.loc[j]["cdsiASIN"] != df.loc[i]["cdsiASIN"]:
                df.at[i, "NofWeeksfromDealfinish"] = 0 
            while j >= 0 and df.loc[j]["cdsiASIN"] == df.loc[i]["cdsiASIN"]: 
                
                if df.loc[j]["cdsiASIN"] != df.loc[i]["cdsiASIN"]:
                    df.at[i, "NofWeeksfromDealfinish"] = 0
                
                elif df.loc[j]["cdsiASIN"] == df.loc[i]["cdsiASIN"] and df.loc[j]["Deal"] == 1.0:
                    df.at[i, "NofWeeksfromDealfinish"] = df.loc[i]["dp_AcquisitionWeek"] - df.loc[j]["dp_AcquisitionWeek"]
                j -= 1 
    
        return df
```

The purpose of the function is to create a novel feature in my dataframe that takes into account the number of weeks that have passed since the Deal (which is a boolean column 1,0) is finished. If there was never a deal I want to have value =0 if the deal is still on I want the value to be 0. If there is no deal and there was one in the past I want to have the count of the weeks that are passed from the moment it was off. I don't have always all the observations for every week so I use the difference between the weeks.
The rows are ordered by cdsiAsin and dp_AcquisitionWeek.

I have created a little dataframe to test this function and it is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'cdsiASIN': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'], '  dp_AcquisitionWeek': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3], 'Deal': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] })
```

And it works as it should:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ2qr.jpg)

But when I apply it to the big dataframe I get as unique values only the value 0 and I know it should not happen:

```
unique_rows = new_df_prova2['NofWeeksfromDealfinish'].unique()
unique_rows 

array([0], dtype=int64)
```

This is the info of the big dataframe:

```
0    cdsiASIN                                          object  
1    dp_AcquisitionWeek                                int64  
2    NofWeeksfromDealfinish                            int64\`
```

I am pretty much lost on what I am doing wrong and I tried to look for clues changing the small dataframe that I use to test but it